# strlen() giving wrong result

Tags: ios, nsstring, strlen, string-length

Currently I'm working on an iOS application, in which I need to convert a `NSString` to `char *`. For this I used the following code:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello ! How Are You ???";
char *as = (char *)[[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes];
int a = strlen(as);
NSLog(@"Length using: -length  : [%d]",[str length]);
NSLog(@"Length using: strlen() : [%d]",a);
```

But the issue is I got different lengths.

Output:

```
Length using: -length  : [23]
Length using: strlen() : [33]
```

I checked it again and again. But sometimes I get correct output. But most of the time I got the wrong result.

What is the issue ? Is there any mistake in my code ?

Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: In addition to the reason given in the answer, note that the two lengths will only be equal if the string contains ASCII characters in the range 1-127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like dataUsingEncoding: does not include '\0' at the end and strlen relies on it. use `char *as = (char *)[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` instead. it gives correct results.

Comment: Even simpler: `char *as = [str UTF8String]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, even though I didn't get the issue. It fixed my issue :)